# Enable Qspectre and Control Flow Guard switch in cmake

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cmake

**I am trying to enable Qspectre and Control Flow Guard (security settings) in cmake. How are these settings enabled in cmake using the cmakefile?**

The [Qspectre](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qspectre?view=vs-2017) and [Control Flow Guard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/guard-enable-control-flow-guard?view=vs-2017) options are both security switches for Visual Studio 2017. QSpectre "specifies compiler generation of instructions to mitigate certain Spectre variant 1 security vulnerabilities" and Control Flow Guard "causes the compiler to analyze control flow for indirect call targets at compile time".

Essentially both are compiler options for security vulnerabilities.

Currently, I am trying to implement using both options in the main cmakefile:

```
if (MSVC AND  NOT MSVC_VERSION LESS 1900)
    if (${use_control_flow_guard}) 
        set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /guard:cf")
        SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "/guard:cf /DYNAMICBASE")
    endif()
    if (${use_qspectre})
        set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /Qspectre")
    endif()
endif()
```

This code is not getting the job done. From a BinSkim (Microsoft Binary Skimmer) check for security vulnerabilities:

- Control Flow Guard:

  error BA2008: '***.dll' does not enable the control flow guard (CFG) mitigation. To resolve this issue, pass /GUARD:CF on both the compiler and linker command lines. Binaries also require the /DYNAMICBASE linker option in order to enable CFG.
- Qspectre:

  The following modules were compiled with a toolset that supports /Qspectre but the switch was not enabled on the command-line

Comment: Where `use_control_flow_guard` variable is set? And to what value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For enabling Control Flow Guard and Qspectre, the above approach is mostly correct in a project.

```
if (MSVC AND (MSVC_VERSION GREATER 1900))
    if (${use_control_flow_guard})
        message("Setting CONTROL FLOW GUARD") 
        set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /guard:cf")
        SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "/guard:cf /DYNAMICBASE")
    endif()
    if (${use_qspectre})
        message("Setting QSPECTRE")
        set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /Qspectre")
    endif()
endif()
```

Because BinSkim is analyzing the `*.dll` files, it will also examine the linked modules within the `.dll` . Thus it could be that the CFG and Qspectre flags are set and compiled with your dynamic library, but libraries that are linked for the project that may not be compiled with Control Flow Guard or Qspectre will create issues and throw errors.

In this instance if the linked modules are from external repositories then there isn't much you can do except acknowledge the vulnerabilities in the linked libraries and move on.