# CMake cannot find SDL2 no matter what I try

Tags: c, cmake, sdl, sdl-2, cmake-language

NOTE This is not a compile time issue this is a cmake generation-time issue.

I've been trying to setup my environment so that cmake can find SDL2.

I am on windows 11, with the latest versions of SDL2 ([found here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.26.3)), SDL_image ([found here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/releases/tag/release-2.6.3)) and SDL_ttf ([found here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/releases/tag/release-2.20.2)) downloaded to the folder `C:/ProgramFilesPublic/`. I used the respective mingw zips for that.

However no matter what I try if its not an issue with finding SDL2 then it can never find SDL2_image or SDL2_ttf no matter what I try.

I tried using `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)` and `find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)` etc.,

then `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED PATHS "C:/ProgramFilesPublic/")` and `find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED PATHS "C:/ProgramFilesPublic/SDL_image")`,

then a few other combinations of that changing that path or adding hints in case that would do it,

then I decided to try https://gitlab.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules.git with `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${SDL_FIND_MODULE_PATH})` and `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)` and `find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)` etc.

I also tried modifying all the paths involved to see if giving it a list of specific files or the directory would fix it, and that didnt do it either.

While none of these worked with SDL2_image or SDL2_ttf, the last at least worked with SDL2.
The last one also gives me an error along the lines of

```
1> [CMake]   By not providing "FindSDL2_image.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
1> [CMake]   has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
1> [CMake]   "SDL2_image", but CMake did not find one.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2_image" with
1> [CMake]   any of the following names:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     SDL2_imageConfig.cmake
1> [CMake]     sdl2_image-config.cmake
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   Add the installation prefix of "SDL2_image" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
1> [CMake]   "SDL2_image_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
1> [CMake]   "SDL2_image" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
1> [CMake]   been installed.
```

Frankly I have no idea why this isn't working. I even checked `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` and it refuses to work even when it has EVERY possible combination of path to the `FindSDL2*.cmake` files needed AT ONCE and even tried adding the `/lib` directory from each SDL folder in my `C:/ProgramFilesPublic/` folder. I've verified this by `message("${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")` witch shows this.

UPDATE: I have currently gotten this far (SDL can be found, however SDL_image and SDL_ttf can't)

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for libcgui, include source and define
# project specific logic here.

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

if (CMAKE_C_CPPCHECK)
    find_program(CMAKE_C_CPPCHECK NAMES cppcheck PATHS "C:/Program Files/Cppcheck" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Cppcheck")
endif()
if(CMAKE_C_CPPCHECK)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_C_CPPCHECK "--enable=all" "--force" "--inline-suppr")
else()
    set(CMAKE_C_CPPCHECK "")
endif()

set(SDL_MIN_VER 2.0.0 CACHE VERSION "The minimum required version for SDL")
set(SDL_IMAGE_MIN_VER 2.0.5 CACHE VERSION "The minimum required version for SDL_image")
set(SDL_TTF_MIN_VER 2.20.2 CACHE VERSION "The minimum required version for SDL_ttf")

set(SDL_FIND_MODULE_PATH "lib/sdl2-cmake-modules" CACHE PATH "The Paths leading to the SDL Finding CMake Modules") #TODO
set(SDL2_PATH "C:/ProgramFilesPublic/SDL2" CACHE PATH "The location to search for SDL2")
set(SDL2_ttf_PATH "C:/ProgramFilesPublic/SDL2_ttf" CACHE PATH "The location to search for SDL2_ttf")
set(SDL2_image_PATH "C:/ProgramFilesPublic/SDL2_image" CACHE PATH "The location to search for SDL2_image")

get_filename_component(SDL_FIND_MODULE_PATH ${SDL_FIND_MODULE_PATH} ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(SDL2_PATH ${SDL2_PATH} ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(SDL2_ttf_PATH ${SDL2_ttf_PATH} ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(SDL2_image_PATH ${SDL2_image_PATH} ABSOLUTE)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${SDL_FIND_MODULE_PATH})
message("${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SDL2_PATH})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SDL2_ttf_PATH})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SDL2_image_PATH})

project ("libcgui" LANGUAGES C)

    #locate sdl and set its variables
    find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
    find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)
    find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
    message("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ${SDL2_image_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_ttf_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}")

    #add the macros:
    set(NO_PRAGMA OFF CACHE BOOL "Disable the use of the #pragma macro. Only useful if your build system doesn't like using it.")
    set(NO_HAS_INCLUDE OFF CACHE BOOL "Disable the use of the __has_include() macro. Only useful if your build system doesn't like using it.")
    set(NO_AUTO_IMPORT OFF CACHE BOOL "Stop trying to import external dependencies in the headers, expect that they will be always imported manually instead.")

    #global build settings
    #set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
    #set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY C_STANDARD 90)
    set(MSVC_EXTRA_OPTIMISE $<MSVC AND MSVC_VERSION GREATER 1900> CACHE BOOL "Enable optimizations for Win32 based platforms")
    set(GNUCC_EXTRA_OPTIMISE $<CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC> CACHE BOOL "Enable optimizations for Unix/Linux based platforms")

    if (NOT SDL2_image_FOUND OR NOT SDL2_ttf_FOUND OR NOT SDL2_FOUND)
        message("SDL and/or it submodules couldn't be found on this system. One solution may be to install sdl development libs manually via the SDL official website binary or another may be to use your package manager.")
        if (WIN32)
            message("For your system I'd suggest downloading the binaries directly")
        else()
            message("For your system I'd suggest checking your package manager first (if possible)")
        endif()
        #TODO return a failure
        #TODO separate errors for each submodule into it own helpful error
    endif()

    #main executable
    add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} "libcgui.c" "libcgui.h" "libcgui_widgets.h" "libcgui_fallbacks.h" "libcgui_backend_SDL2.h" "libcgui_widgets.c" "libcgui_backend_SDL2.c" "libcgui_backend_helpers.h")
    
        #target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_ttf_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_image_INCLUDE_DIRS})
        target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "lib/")
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_image_LIBRARIES})
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_ttf_LIBRARIES})

        if (NO_PRAGMA)
            target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC NO_PRAGMA)
        endif()

        if (NO_HAS_INCLUDE)
            target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC NO_HAS_INCLUDE)
        endif()

        if (NO_AUTO_IMPORT)
            target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC NO_AUTO_IMPORT)
        endif()

        if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
            #from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855121/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-pedantic-in-the-gcc-g-compiler
            
            target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra)
        endif()

        if (GNUCC_EXTRA_OPTIMISE)
            #from https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GCC_optimization
            target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -O3 -fPIC)
        endif()
        
        if(MSVC AND MSVC_VERSION GREATER 1900)
            target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Wall)
            if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL Debug)
                target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -VERBOSE)
            endif()
        endif()

        if (MSVC_EXTRA_OPTIMISE)
            #from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160599/enable-qspectre-and-control-flow-guard-switch-in-cmake
            message("Setting CONTROL FLOW GUARD and QSPECTERE") 
            target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -GUARD:CF -Qspectre -Ot )
            target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -GUARD:CF -DYNAMICBASE)
                
            if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL Debug)
                target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -OPT:REF,ICF,LBR)
            endif()
        endif()
```

Comment: 1. Make sure that you have downloaded **devel** packages, which aside from `.dll` contains `.lib` and `.h` files. 2. Add to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable a directory which contains `FindSDL.cmake` and similar scripts. 3. Add to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable installation directories of `SDL`, `SDL_image` and others. *Installation directory* is the one contained `lib` and `include` subdirectories. 4. Use `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)` form, without additional parameters like PATHS.

Comment: I am sure I have downloaded the right packages. They have the folders ```/lib```, which contains both 64x and 86x ```.dll```s and ```.lib```s and ```/include``` which has all the ```.h```s, and ```/cmake``` which has the ```.cmake``` files in it as well (for SDL only and noth SDL2_image or SDL2_ttf there is also a ```/doc``` folder but I doubt that changes things).

Comment: When you say add ```FindSLD.cmake``` to the module path, do you mean the ```.cmake``` files included with the libraries or the FindSDL2.cmake modules I was trying to use?

Comment: I mean `FindSDL2.cmake` and other modules which you get from https://gitlab.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules.git. Even if you get the error message after proper setting `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable, then that message shouldn't contain lines like `By not providing "FindSDL2_image.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. Update your question post with the error message in that case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've tried what you said and now SDL can be found, however SDL_image and SDL_ttf can't

Comment: @Tsyvarev also updated the question with my ```CMakeLists.txt```

Comment: The variable [CMAKE_MODULE_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) should contain **absolute** paths, but the path `cmake/sdl2-cmake-modules` is *relative*. When construct an absolute path you could the fact that `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` refers to the directory with the currently processed `CMakeLsits.txt`.

Comment: And `SDL2_TTF` is the wrong name for the package. Correct name is `SDL2_ttf`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have shown the changes I've made above and now I get the error ```Could NOT find SDL2 (missing: SDL2_LIBRARY SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)```.

Comment: Good, the error message has changed. Now it is time to properly set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, as I described in my first comment.

Comment: @Tsyvarev as shown above (```list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SDL2_PATH} ${SDL2_ttf_PATH} ${SDL2_image_PATH})```), I have already done that. Is this done in the wrong way? ```list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SDL2_PATH})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SDL2_ttf_PATH})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SDL2_image_PATH})``` does not work either. All paths are also absolute.

Comment: "Is this done in the wrong way?" - It depends on which exact paths you passed via `SDL2_PATH` and other variables. The default value - `mysdlpath` - is definitely wrong. When post the exact value of these variables, post also the exact (absolute) path of `SDL.h` header, which is located under the SDL2 installation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ```mysdlpath``` is the path to the folder that contains ```lib``` and ```include``` (and ```cmake``` etc.) folders found in the SDL development binary .zips

Comment: Several comments before you assured me that your put proper path into `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. The problem has been found once you post the actual value. Now you assure me about proper path to SDL.. What is the reason to ask "Where could be a problem in my code", but instead of the exact code and exact values provide their *description*?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I was hpoing to keep things brief to avoid confusion however here is the full ```CMakeLists.txt```:

Comment: Assuming you have CMake 3.17 or newer, you could run cmake with additional `--debug-find` option. That way CMake will print where commands like `find_path` actually search files. From that output find out where `SDL.h` file is actually searched. FYI, setting `SDL2_PATH` variable is by itself sufficient to hint the script [FindSDL2.cmake](https://gitlab.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules/-/blob/master/FindSDL2.cmake). This is written in the beginning of the script.